# How to Modify Element in CKEditor

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor

I have CKEditor with `config.fullPage = true;`, so I have an entire document to work with.

My goal is to automatically find and modify the action of all `form` elements in the CKEditor content. I've tried using the method of converting the html string to jquery and back with no luck (I think it's because I'm working with a full document).

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: you want to modify all form elements in CkEditor??

Comment: Yeah, similar to what I might do in jquery with $("form").attr("action","")

Comment: that is you want to Create an element based on a native DOM element. in CKEditor

Answer (score 2):

If `editor` is the instance of your CKEditor, then calling `editor.editable().$` will get you the native body element of the iframe, then you can keep using DOM methods or jQuery if you prefer.

```
jQuery(editor.editable().$).find('form').attr('action', '');
```

Comment: Converting it to jquery works great, though I'm having quite a bit of difficulty getting the HTML string back from jquery. Since ```editor.editable().$``` represents a list of DOM elements, just calling ```.html()``` on the jquery string isn't giving back the full HTML.

Comment: I don't understand what do you want to do. If you want to get the full HTML the use the CKEditor API and call editor.getData() I fail to understand why you want to use jQuery

Comment: I can get the HTML string with editor.getData(). What I want to do is to then treat that string like a dom and use jquery to modify any form elements that were in that HTML string. Then, I want to convert that modified dom back to a string so I can send it via an API call back to my database. Basically, instead of doing find/replace on an HTML string, I'd prefer to use jquery as a middleman if possible to be more accurate.

Comment: I think that you're overcomplicating things. Stop, read again my answer, read the example code and you'll see that I don't convert anything to a string and used jQuery as you requested

Comment: This works great when the editor is in "preview" mode. The second hurdle is that this doesn't work when the editor is in source mode. I can use ```execCommand("source")``` to switch between the two, but it's async and there doesn't appear to be a way to just run your code when it's done.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE**

check this [CKEditor Jquery Adapter](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_jquery) and you can also get HTML of the element with [.getHtml](http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.dom.element.html#getHtml) .

**ANOTHER UPDATE**

```
$("#mybutton").click(function(){
    var editor_contents = CKEDITOR.instances[YOUR_TEXTAREA_ID].getData();
    var dom = document.createElement("DIV");
    dom.innerHTML = editor_contents
    var plain_text = (dom.textContent || dom.innerText);
    alert(plain_text);
});
```

Comment: This is fine for creating a new element, but my goal is to find all existing form elements and replace an attribute in them.

The use case is that I have users saving full HTML documents that contain forms. On a button click that saves the document, I want to modify the forms found in the HTML document to have a different attribute.

Comment: this attribute you want to replace in existing form element, what should it be doing like its functionality

Comment: Thanks for the updates! The ```.replace()``` function isn't quite what I'm looking for, since it appears to replace the found element with a full CKEditor instance.

What I'm trying to do is to have functionality that, when a user clicks "Save", for example, I will automatically parse the HTML that is the ```editor.val()``` for any form elements and change their action attribute. Then, I send the full (modified) HTML string off to an API.

In a nutshell, I need to be able to modify the elements *in the CKEditor HTML* and get the resulting full HTML string.

Comment: like you want to get the content of the element in the CKEditor HTML string or inner HTML

Comment: I want to get the HTML string that represents the HTML the user input into CKEditor.